# Trying to convert from mysqli to pdo

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, pdo

```
try {
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbusername, $dbpassword);
} catch (PDOException $e){
exit('Datebase error.');
}
// db login info is already defined, just didnt post it here

$username = $_GET["user"];
$password = $_GET["passwd"];
//$data = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='".$username."'");
//$hash = mysqli_fetch_object($data);
$query = "SELECT username, password, loginreqkey, banned FROM users WHERE username='$username'";

//if (password_verify('rasmuslerdorf', $hash)) {
if ($stmt = $pdo->prepare($query)) {
$stmt->execute(array($username, $password, $loginreqkey, $banned));
//$stmt->bind_result($username, $password, $loginreqkey, $gbanned);
//  $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_LAZY);
//$dt = $stmt->fetchAll()   ;
 //$query->execute(array($username, $password));
if (password_verify($password, $result['password'])) {

while($r = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
 echo "{";
 echo '"state": "success",';
    echo '"loginreqkey": "' . $r['loginreqkey'] . '",';
     echo '"banstatus": "' . $r['banned'] . '"';
    echo "}";
}

/* close statement */
$stmt = null;
} else {
die("fake pw lol");
}

/* close connection */
$pdo = null;
}
//}
```

Trying to convert my code from MySQLi to PDO and having issues.. trying to get all the information in query and verify the user password then echo the rest of the information, (for an unreal project) tried a couple of solutions on php documentation and stackoverflow but they were usually just for sending information to the mysql server.

Comment: So what is not working? Errors?

Comment: `$stmt->execute(array($username, $password, $loginreqkey, $banned));` why are you doing this? You don't have any parameters in your query.

Comment: Btw: `$password = $_GET["passwd"]` - Really? Ok, POST parameters are not really secure; but at least they don't end up in the browser history or a cache so f*ing easily.

Comment: @VolkerK its sent from a program over SSL so there is no browser post parameter

Answer (score 2):

```
$username = $_GET["user"];
$password = $_GET["passwd"];

$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname;charset=utf8", $dbusername, $dbpassword, array(
  PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE=>PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION // ....since there is no further error handling in the script
));

$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT username, password, loginreqkey, banned FROM users WHERE username=:username");
$stmt->bindParam(':username', $username);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if ($result && password_verify($password, $result['password'])) {
    echo json_encode [
        "state" => "success",
        "loginreqkey" => $result['loginreqkey'],
        "banstatus" => $result['banned'],
    ];
}
```

That's how I would go about it.

Comment: @Your Common Sense : Thx, I was just about to comment on that matter ;-)

Comment: @VolkerK which one? manual JSON formatting I guess? :) I also fixed empty $result issue.

Comment: Actually both, but I meant the "no such record"/result thingy ;-)

Comment: I have no real experience using JSON, hence why I didn't write it using JSON notation.

Comment: Yet you always should.

Comment: @SGR Thanks for the help but all that happens is a blank page, even with php errors enabled :/

Answer (score -1):

Just for completeness: It looks like you've tried to bind the results fields via `$stmt->execute(array(...))`. That's not how PDO works.
If you want to do that you'll have to use [PDOStatement::bindColumn](http://php.net/manual/de/pdostatement.bindcolumn.php) like e.g.

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test;charset=utf8', 'localonly', 'localonly', array(
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES=>false,
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_DIRECT_QUERY=>false,
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE=>PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
));
setup($pdo);

$username = $_GET["user"];
$password = $_GET["passwd"];

$query = sprintf(
    "SELECT username, `password`, loginreqkey, banned FROM users WHERE username='%s'",
    $pdo->quote($username)
);
$stmt = $pdo->query($query);
$stmt->bindColumn(1, $username);
$stmt->bindColumn(2, $password);
$stmt->bindColumn(3, $loginreqkey);
$stmt->bindColumn(4, $banned);

if ( !$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOUND) ) {
    noSuchRecordHandler();
}
else if (!password_verify($password, $result['password'])) {
    wrongPasswordHandler();
}
else {
    // would be "nice" if there was something like header('Content-type: application/json'); prior to sending the json data
    echo json_encode([
        "state" => "success",
        "loginreqkey" => loginreqkey,
        "banstatus" => $banned,
    ]);
}
```

But I suggest doing it as shown in [SGR's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36057609/4833) answer.